What are the benefits of Narshimha Kavacham (by Prahlada Maharaj) in Hindu scriptures?
Basically the title.
What are the said benefits of Narshimha Kavacham?
Is it true that one with purified heart who chants it 32,000 times gets liberation?
Please give proper Shastra References.
